How to generate UUID in Conductor Workflow
I want to create a workflow that will generate a UUID, so that it can be passed to another task in the workflow: whenever the workflow task executes, it gets a new UUID.

The workflow below generates a UUID.
Inside the Conductor UI on the browser, go to the Definitions tab, click on New Workflow Definition, delete any existing content, and add the code below.


{
  "createTime": 1733483033480,
  "updateTime": 1733640757965,
  "accessPolicy": {},
  "name": "generate_uuid",
  "description": "generate_uuid",
  "version": 1,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "generate_uuid_ref",
      "taskReferenceName": "generate_uuid_ref",
      "inputParameters": {
        "expression": "(function () {\n  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {\n    var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0, v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8;\n    return v.toString(16);\n  });\n})();",
        "evaluatorType": "javascript"
      },
      "type": "INLINE",
      "startDelay": 0,
      "optional": false,
      "asyncComplete": false
    }
  ],
  "inputParameters": [],
  "outputParameters": {
    "uuid": "${generate_uuid_ref.output.result}"
  },
  "failureWorkflow": "",
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "restartable": true,
  "workflowStatusListenerEnabled": false,
  "ownerEmail": "example@email.com",
  "timeoutPolicy": "ALERT_ONLY",
  "timeoutSeconds": 0,
  "variables": {},
  "inputTemplate": {}
}



